# Pipe coming off of boiler

Tags: leak, boiler

wondering what the copper-colored pipe coming off of my boiler is? It's never done anything before but recently started leaking some water (not much, but that's why I've got a tray there now). And is this something expected?

[image]

Comment: My guess is a pressure relief valve. Not confident in that though, or what you would do to fix it, so not submitting an official answer

Comment: Definitely a temperature/pressure relief valve. It is designed to let water out if it gets too hot or too high pressure so that the boiler doesn't burst. The valve itself could be failing, and they are replaceable. Or it could be an indication that the boiler is not functioning properly. I'll let someone with more plumbing knowledge give an official answer, because that's about all I know about them.

Comment: There should be  a combination pressure/temperature gauge attached to your boiler. Check the readings. Most relief valves are set to open at 30 psi. If the gauge is well  below that, that the valve is faulty which does happen. If the gauge is reading near 30 psi, then the boiler has a problem and you should get it serviced as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a temperature/pressure relief valve. It's probably leaking due to internal damage or age. There is a slight chance that it is leaking due to an overpressure event, but that's unlikely as typically when something like that happens it's usually releasing a whole lot more water than this, and maybe also some steam.

There's two approaches you can take here.

1. Assume it's just the valve. Let the boiler down to stone cold. This might take quite a while depending on the size of your system. Once you think it's cold, lift the lever on the valve to confirm that it is cold. Be prepared, if the boiler is not as cold as you think it is, hot water might spray out of this pipe. Once you've confirmed that the pressure is gone, you can replace the valve with an identical or suitable replacement valve. The replacement is similar to replacing any plumbing valve, of which there is a lot written about already on this site.
2. Confirm that there is no other problem. Bring in a boiler tech (hopefully whoever does your annual inspection) to confirm that this is not due to a larger problem with the boiler. Most likely they will find it is just the valve, and proceed to do option 1.

The second option is the safer one. If you're comfortable replacing a valve, though, the first option isn't that dangerous. Since you will be installing a new T&P valve, if the system is over pressure it will just continue to leak.

Whatever you do, don't cap the valve off or replace it with a normal non-T&P valve.

Comment: Oh and if you do cap it off, this is what could happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGWmONHipVo